# How to save the response from the elastic search index into s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

How to generate below my-index

1. create a env in your local
2. install necessary libraries (elasticsearch,requests,requests_aws4auth,boto3) using pip
3. create file inside `env\Lib\site-packages\` with lambda_function.py and add the below code
4. Zip the above folder and name it as lambda_function.zip and upload into lambda function where you create the function with necessary IAM role

   ```
    import boto3
    from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    credentials = session.get_credentials()

    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                       credentials.secret_key,
                       session.region_name, 'es',
                       session_token=credentials.token)
    es = Elasticsearch(
        ['https://search-testelastic-2276kyz2u4l3basec63onfq73a.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
        http_auth=awsauth,
        use_ssl=True,
        verify_certs=True,
        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
    )


    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        es.cluster.health()
        es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
        r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
     {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}]
        for e in enumerate(r):
             es.index(index="my-index", body=e[1])
   ```

Response is below

`{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":3,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"my-index_1","_type":"_doc","_id":"elqrJHMB10jKFvejVaNM","_score":1.0,"_source":{"Name":"Dr. Christopher DeSimone","Specialised and Location":"Health"}},{"_index":"my-index_1","_type":"_doc","_id":"e1qrJHMB10jKFvejVqMK","_score":1.0,"_source":{"Name":"Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)","Specialised and Location":"Health"}},{"_index":"my-index_1","_type":"_doc","_id":"fFqrJHMB10jKFvejVqMR","_score":1.0,"_source":{"Name":"Dr. Bernard M. Aaron","Specialised and Location":"Health"}}]}}`

- How to save the above response in as json in folder in s3 bucket

bucket name = test20220elastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse your `session` object to create a S3 resource:

```
es = ...
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('test20220elastic')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
    for e in enumerate(r):
        result = es.index(index="my-index", body=e[1])
        bucket.put_object(Body=json.dumps(result), Key="my_folder/my_result.json",
                          ContentType="application/json")
```

You'll probably want build a different key name for each result, though.

Comment: can you answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808166/how-to-create-a-layer-in-lambda-function