# How to create a layer in lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Steps followed to create

1. Create a virtual environment and activate it
2. pip install elasticsearch
3. Zip the folder inside site-packages.zip

4.Create Layer in AWS (say name is `elastic`)

5. Add the code below in lambda_handler and add  the Layer `elastic`

Below is code

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Still I got   `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'elasticsearch'",`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I may, I would like to recommend an alternative technique which has never failed me. The technique includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus for this question, I **verified it** using `elasticsearch` as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
elasticsearch
```

3. Run the following docker command (may adjust python version to your needs):

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r elastic.zip python > /dev/null
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `elastic.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import json

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    print(dir(Elasticsearch))
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The function executes correctly:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bulk', 'clear_scroll', 'close', 'count', 'create', 'delete', 'delete_by_query', 'delete_by_query_rethrottle', 'delete_script', 'exists', 'exists_source', 'explain', 'field_caps', 'get', 'get_script', 'get_script_context', 'get_script_languages', 'get_source', 'index', 'info', 'mget', 'msearch', 'msearch_template', 'mtermvectors', 'ping', 'put_script', 'rank_eval', 'reindex', 'reindex_rethrottle', 'render_search_template', 'scripts_painless_execute', 'scroll', 'search', 'search_shards', 'search_template', 'termvectors', 'update', 'update_by_query', 'update_by_query_rethrottle']
```

Comment: Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:build-python3.8' locally

Comment: I installed docker and started docker desktop

Comment: @aysh Seems like a new issue. Maybe can make new question with relevant info and error messages?

Answer (score 0):

As one option is already mentioned by @Marcin which is required Docker to be installed in the target machine. If you want to skip docker then you can use below script to create and publish layer to AWS.

All you need

```
./creater_layer.sh <package_name> <layer_name>

./creater_layer.sh elasticsearch my-layer
```

script `creater_layer.sh`

```
path="app"
package="${1}"
layername="${2}"
mkdir -p $path
pip3 install "${package}" --target "${path}/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/"
cd $path && zip -r ../lambdalayer.zip .
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name "${layername}" --description "My layer" --license-info "MIT" --zip-file "fileb://../lambdalayer.zip" --compatible-runtimes python3.8
```

Comment: Sir How to do in windows machine?

Comment: You can use git bash in window, no changes will required in script

Comment: can you answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109212/how-to-push-the-data-from-dynamodb-through-stream

Answer (score 0):

For MacOs users, if you're not specifying the platform while installing the library using pip, you'll have issues importing the library from the lambda function. To fix that, this how you should create the layer properly:

1. create an empty folder called "python" :

   > `mkdir python`
2. install the library using pip3 by specifying the platform, target, implementation and python version:

   > `pip3 install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=python --implementation cp --python-version 3.10 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade library-name`
3. Zip the library you have just downloaded using pip3

   > `zip -r library-name.zip python`

You can then upload the library-name.zip while creating the layer on AWS. It solved the issue for me.