# How to push the data from dynamodb through stream

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Below is the json file

```
[
    {
        "year": 2013,
        "title": "Rush",
        "actors": [
                "Daniel Bruhl",
                "Chris Hemsworth",
                "Olivia Wilde"
            ]
        
    },
    {
        "year": 2013,
        "title": "Prisoners",
        "actors": [
                "Hugh Jackman",
                "Jake Gyllenhaal",
                "Viola Davis"
            ]
        }
]
```

Below is the code to push to dynamodb. I have created `testjsonbucket` bucket name, `moviedataten.json` is the filename and saved above json.Create a dynamodb with Primary partition key   as year (Number) and
Primary sort key as title (String).

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
import json
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('testjsonbucket', 'moviedataten.json')
body = obj.json
#def lambda_handler(event,context):
#    print (body)

def load_movies(movies, dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')
    for movie in movies:
        year = int(movie['year'])
        title = movie['title']
        print("Adding movie:", year, title)
        table.put_item(Item=movie)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    movie_list = json.loads(body, parse_float=Decimal)
    load_movies(movie_list)
```

- I want to push in to ElasticSearch from dynamodb.
- I have created a Elastic Domain `https://xx.x.x.com/testelas`
- I have gone through the link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/
- I clicked Managestream also

My Requirement:

Any change in Dynamodb has to reflect in the Elasticsearch?

Comment: Have you created a [stream in DynanoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) connected to your lambda?

Comment: Yes i have enabled Latest stream ARN arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xx:table/Movies/stream/2020-07-27T03:10:02.586

Comment: Can you clairfiy what is the issue? Any error messages, or timeouts, ...?

Comment: @Marcin I need a lambda code to push in to elasticsearch from dynamodb. If any modification in dynamodb will result in update the document in Elasticsearch also

Comment: I have added function name for triggering from dynamodb

Comment: I see. So the current code needs to be modified.

Comment: @Marcin yes g, current code need to modified or  new lambda function also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lambda just writing the document to DynamoDb, and I will not recommend adding the code in this lambda to push the same object to Elastic search, as lambda function **should perform a single task** and pushing the same document to ELK should be managed as a **[DynamoDB stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)**.

- What if ELK is down or not available how you will manage this in lambda?
- What if you want to disable this in future? you will need to modify lambda instead of controlling this from AWS API or AWS console, all you need to just disable the stream when required no changes on above lambda side code
- What if you want to move only modify or TTL item to elastic search?

So create Dyanodb Stream that pushes the document to another Lambda that is responsible to push the document to ELK, with this option you can also push old and new both items.

[image]

You can look into this article too that describe another approach [data-streaming-from-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch](https://medium.com/realtime-data-streaming/data-streaming-from-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch-eb2381446f43)

For above approach look into this GitHub project [dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch](https://github.com/matrus2/dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch).

```
const { pushStream } = require('dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch');

const { ES_ENDPOINT, INDEX, TYPE } = process.env;

function myHandler(event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  pushStream({ event, endpoint: ES_ENDPOINT, index: INDEX, type: TYPE })
    .then(() => {
      callback(null, `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      callback(`Error ${e}`, null);
    });
}

exports.handler = myHandler;
```

Comment: do you have info in python Adii?

Comment: yes you can look into this Github https://github.com/vladhoncharenko/aws-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch which does same as above function

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504899/how-to-add-log-info-in-the-code-in-lambda

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB has a built in feature ([DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)) that will handle the stream part of this question.

When you configure this you have the choice of the following configurations:

- `KEYS_ONLY` — Only the key attributes of the modified item.
- `NEW_IMAGE` — The entire item, as it appears after it was modified.
- `OLD_IMAGE` — The entire item, as it appeared before it was modified.
- `NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES` — Both the new and the old images of the item.

This will [produce an event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html#with-dbb-invoke-manually) that looks like the following

```
{
   "Records":[
      {
         "eventID":"1",
         "eventName":"INSERT",
         "eventVersion":"1.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:dynamodb",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "dynamodb":{
            "Keys":{
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "NewImage":{
               "Message":{
                  "S":"New item!"
               },
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "SequenceNumber":"111",
            "SizeBytes":26,
            "StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
         },
         "eventSourceARN":"stream-ARN"
      },
      {
         "eventID":"2",
         "eventName":"MODIFY",
         "eventVersion":"1.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:dynamodb",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "dynamodb":{
            "Keys":{
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "NewImage":{
               "Message":{
                  "S":"This item has changed"
               },
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "OldImage":{
               "Message":{
                  "S":"New item!"
               },
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "SequenceNumber":"222",
            "SizeBytes":59,
            "StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
         },
         "eventSourceARN":"stream-ARN"
      },
      {
         "eventID":"3",
         "eventName":"REMOVE",
         "eventVersion":"1.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:dynamodb",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "dynamodb":{
            "Keys":{
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "OldImage":{
               "Message":{
                  "S":"This item has changed"
               },
               "Id":{
                  "N":"101"
               }
            },
            "SequenceNumber":"333",
            "SizeBytes":38,
            "StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
         },
         "eventSourceARN":"stream-ARN"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you're already familiar with Lambda it makes sense to use a Lambda function to consume the records and then iterate through them to process them in the Elasticsearch format before adding them to your index.

When doing this make sure that you iterate through **each record** as there may be multiple depending on your configuration.

For more information on the steps required for the Lambda side of the function check out the [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.htm) page.

Comment: I tried the question in below link, same issue I got same output as like the questionnaire. can you check once please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455543/how-to-get-the-column-names-in-redshift-using-python-boto3