# How to add log info in the Code in python in the loop

Tags: python, logging

- Below is the dictionary
- There are two ids, I need to generat
- Once extract of completion of first id i need to get an info saying First id(100) is completed
- Once extract of completion of second id i need to get an info saying second id(101) is completed

`logger.info('extraction id' + str(id) + 'completed')`

`logger.info('extraction id' + + str(id) + 'completed')`

Expected out

```
    test = [{"id":"100","name":"A",
    "Business":[{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Customer"}],
    "policies":[{"id":"332","name":"Second division","parent":"Marketing"},
    {"id":"3323","name":"First division","parent":"Marketing"}]},
    {"id":"101","name":"B",
    "Business":[{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Customer"}],
    "policies":[{"id":"332","name":"Second division","parent":"Marketing"},
    {"id":"3323","name":"First division","parent":"Marketing"}]}]
```

code

```
def do_the_thing(lst):
    resp = []

    parents_mapper = {
        'Marketing': 'level1',
        'Advertising': 'level2'
    }

    for el in lst:
        d = {
            'id': el['id'],
            'name': el['name'],
            'Business': [],
            'level1': [],
            'level2': []
        }
        for business in el.get('Business', []):
            business_name = business.get('name')
            if business_name:
                d['Business'].append(business_name)

        for policy in el.get('policies', []):
            policy_parent = policy.get('parent')
            parent_found = parents_mapper.get(policy_parent)
            policy_name = policy.get('name')
            if parent_found and policy_name:
                d[parent_found].append(policy_name)

        resp.append(d)
    return resp


#def lambda_handler(event,context):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(do_the_thing(test))
```

output for 2 ids

```
[
  {
    "id": "100",
    "name": "A",
    "Business": ["Enterprise", "Customer"],
    "level1": ['Second division', 'First division'],
    "level2": [None ]
  },
  {
    "id": "101",
    "name": "B",
    "Business": ["Enterprise", "Customer"],
    "level1": ['Second division', 'First division'],
    "level2": [None ]
  }
]
```

First id completed then i will get `extraction id' 100 is completed'` second id completed then i will get `extraction id' 10` is completed'`

** Expected out_one

```
extraction id' 100 is completed'
extraction id' 101 is completed'
```

** Expected out_two

```
extraction Business' 100 is completed'
extraction policy' 100 is completed'
extraction level1' 100 is completed'
extraction Business' 101 is completed'
extraction policy' 101 is completed'
extraction level1' 101 is completed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', filename='output.log',level=logging.INFO)

test = [{"id":"100","name":"A",
    "Business":[{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Customer"}],
    "policies":[{"id":"332","name":"Second division","parent":"Marketing"},
    {"id":"3323","name":"First division","parent":"Marketing"}]},
    {"id":"101","name":"B",
    "Business":[{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Customer"}],
    "policies":[{"id":"332","name":"Second division","parent":"Marketing"},
    {"id":"3323","name":"First division","parent":"Marketing"}]}]

def do_the_thing(lst):
    resp = []

    parents_mapper = {
        'Marketing': 'level1',
        'Advertising': 'level2'
    }

    for el in lst:
        d = {
            'id': el['id'],
            'name': el['name'],
            'Business': [],
            'level1': [],
            'level2': []
        }

        for business in el.get('Business', []):
            business_name = business.get('name')
            if business_name:
                d['Business'].append(business_name)

        if business:
            logging.info(f"extraction Business' {d['id']} is completed'")

        parents = []
        for policy in el.get('policies', []):
            policy_parent = policy.get('parent')
            parent_found = parents_mapper.get(policy_parent)
            policy_name = policy.get('name')
            if parent_found and policy_name:
                d[parent_found].append(policy_name)
                if parent_found not in parents:
                    logging.info(f"extraction {parent_found}' {d['id']} is completed'")
                    parents.append(parent_found)

        if policy:
            logging.info(f"extraction policy' {d['id']} is completed'")

        logging.info(f"extraction id' {d['id']} is completed'")

        resp.append(d)

    return resp


#def lambda_handler(event,context):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    print("Behold Magic in Progress...")
    the_thing_result = do_the_thing(test)
    print("\nThe parsed dictionary:")
    pp.pprint(the_thing_result)
```

Has both outputs:

Output:

```
Behold Magic in Progress...

The parsed dictionary:
[   {   'Business': ['Enterprise', 'Customer'],
        'id': '100',
        'level1': ['Second division', 'First division'],
        'level2': [],
        'name': 'A'},
    {   'Business': ['Enterprise', 'Customer'],
        'id': '101',
        'level1': ['Second division', 'First division'],
        'level2': [],
        'name': 'B'}]
```

Log in 'output.log':

```
extraction Business' 100 is completed'
extraction level1' 100 is completed'
extraction policy' 100 is completed'
extraction id' 100 is completed'
extraction Business' 101 is completed'
extraction level1' 101 is completed'
extraction policy' 101 is completed'
extraction id' 101 is completed'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure with what you mean with "** Expected out_two" But here's how to implement logging

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger
logger.setLevel('INFO')

logging.info("This is information")
logging.warning("This is a warning!")
```

Roughly implemented in your problem:

```
import logging
import pprint

test = ...

def do_the_thing(lst):
    ...
    for el in lst:
        ...
        for business in el.get('Business', []):
            ...


        for policy in el.get('policies', []):
            ...
        resp.append(d)

        logging.info(f"extraction id {d['id']} is completed")
    return resp


#def lambda_handler(event,context):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel('INFO')

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(do_the_thing(test))
```

Which results in logs

```
INFO:root:extraction id 100 is completed
INFO:root:extraction id 101 is completed
```

Comment: can you do ** Expected out_two

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean... @nons